# How to wait for element.all().each() to resolve before proceeding

Tags: javascript, selenium, promise, protractor, end-to-end

I'm trying to iterate through a list of elements to find if any one of them has a particular value as it's `getText()` value.

My problem is that my test is not executing in the order I've laid it out.

I've read a bunch about queuing and Promise resolution, but I don't understand how it affects my current scenario.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
it('should find apps by name', function() {
    var exists = false;

    element.all(by.repeater(‘item in list’).each(function(elem) {
        elem.getText().then(function(text) {
            if(text == 'foo') 
                exists = true;
            return exists;
        }).then(function(exists) {
            console.log('interim value: ' + exists);  // This appears after
        });
    });

    console.log('final status: ' + exists);   // This appears in the console first
})
```

Any insight into how I can determine what I want the value of my boolean to be *before* I log it at the end would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protractor is of an asynchronous nature - everything is a promise and controlled by a [Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md):

> WebDriverJS (and thus, Protractor) APIs are entirely asynchronous. All
>   functions return promises.
>
> WebDriverJS maintains a queue of pending promises, called the control
>   flow, to keep execution organized.

In other words, don't expect the code to work from top to bottom.

Since you need a single boolean value indicating that there is a desired element - `each()` is not a good choice - it would just apply a function to every element. Use [`reduce()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce) instead:

```
var exists = element.all(by.repeater("item in list")).reduce(function(acc, elem) {
    return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
        return !acc ? text === 'foo' : acc;
    });
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you.  That was very helpful.

Comment: Surely after the first iteration, `acc` will be a promise, not a boolean.

Comment: And the scan operation needs to be fixed. As it stands a second 'foo' would revert the boolean to `false`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 `acc` is always staying a boolean during the iterations. But, fixed the scan operation, thanks for the point.

Comment: Interesting, I ran an (admittedly modified version of) your script and it confirmed my impression that returning a thenable from the reduce callback would cause the next iteration's `previous` (ie `acc`) to be a promise. I can't see that it could be otherwise.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 ok, but how about the example from the docs? (http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce) Do you see `acc` as promise in this case too?

Comment: Ah OK my mistake, I was assuming `Array.prototype.reduce` not `ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce`, which seems to behave as you say. Appologies, I should have followed your link!