# How can I implement a step definition method for a line in feature file which tests for multiple values in a protractor-cucumber framework?

Tags: selenium, protractor, automated-tests, cucumber, chai

**Feature file(In gherkins) line:**
Then I should see "New Order,Old Order,Contact,City,Country,Account,Tier" text appearing in attributes column

**Step Definition which I implemeted** which doesn't seem to work:

```
this.Then(/^I should see "([^"]*)" text appearing in attributes column$/, function (arg1/*,callback*/) {
    varattributeNames = arg1.split(",");
    varattributesGroup = element.all(by.css('css-selector')).each((ele,index)=>{
        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(ele)).then(()=>{
            expect(ele.getText()).to.eventually.equal(attributeNames[index]);
        });
        //if(index+1===attributeNames.length){
        //callback();
        //}
    });
});
```

I am passing all these column attribute names to step definition method. I want it to wait for expect statements to finish fully. But instead it is returning as soon as the 'each' loop gets over and not waiting for all the expect statements to fully resolve.

**Note**: I have used "ignoreSynchronisation = true" in protractor-conf.js as the webpage I am testing is not fully angular.

Comment: Don't use each loop instead go with reduce as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790336/how-to-wait-for-element-all-each-to-resolve-before-proceeding

Comment: I will face the same problem with reduce too.
reduce is preferable when we want to return a single element: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777577/breaking-out-of-a-protractor-filter-or-map-loop

Comment: Jainam can't post to StackOverflow from work (finance co), but I can: he says "it turns out that browser.wait is waiting indefinitely, and .each() being a promise was not working to go into the function body".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` method for these scenarios-

```
this.Then(/^I should see "([^"]*)" text appearing in attributes column$/, function (arg1/*,callback*/) {

varattributeNames = arg1.split(",");

varattributesGroup = element.all(by.css('css-selector')).map((ele,index)=>{
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(ele)).then(()=>{
        return ele.getText().then(function(text) {
                return text;
              });
    });

     //varattributesGroup should have your texts in an array.
     //deep equal is used to compare objects/nested arrays in chai assertions

     expect(varattributesGroup).to.eventually.deep.equal(varattributeNames);
});
});
```

Also `cucumber.js` supports promises no need of `callbacks`. Please have a look at this [link](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md).

Comment: This is making browser.wait line wait indefinitely. I am using the right selectors.